# Resume already running app when sharing

Tags: android, authentication, share, restart

I am developing an app for sending files and my problem is that when I share some file from outside, it always starts a new instance of the app, even if an already instance is running. To put it another way: I have to log in every time when I share something, even if I am already running the app in the background.

Are there any workarounds for this?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set `android:alwaysRetainTaskState="true"` and `android:launchMode="singleInstance"` to your very first activity in AndroidManifest

Comment: it does not work. when I try to share a file it still launches a new instance.

Comment: paste your AndroidManifest and the code where you do this sharing by launching (if any) activity

Comment: the problem is that the launcher activity, which has the action.SEND action is no longer available because it is already destroyed. (it is a login window, after login I destroy it). But if I add <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" /> to any other activity, which does live, the program crashes. Can you help me with that? Thanks.

Comment: if you dont destroy your login activity, will it affect the flow of your application?

Comment: yes. I don't want the user to be able to go back to the login window by hitting the back button. But I managed to solve this issue. I set the other activities android:launchMode="singleInstance" and I start the launcher activity, but in the oncreate, if it is already started (I set some boolean value) then I navigate to a specific window. This way it works. But thanks for the tip with these two attributes.